# Where to add manual scripts to a Java Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I'm used to work with interpreted languages where we can simply create scripts to test a piece of code and maybe debug them easily.

For example, I could create a `scripts/test-something.py` file, add my code there, and simply run `scripts/test-something.py` on the console.

I started to work with Java (with Maven) and I couldn't find a good way to do something similar.

I wanted to create a bash script where I can run these "manual" test classes, but these test classes are not exactly test code, that have assertions and mocks, for example. They are code that runs as if I was running the application locally, using real dependencies (and not mocks).

My idea was to add, for example, the file `scripts/run-manual-script.sh` which would accept a class name as an argument, to run this class (the main method).

These manual scripts would be in the `src/manual-scripts/java/com/...` folder.

However, when I run `scripts/run-manual-script.sh`, it doesn't find the class that I added to the `src/manual-scripts` folder, because (I think) this is not a standard Maven directory.

So, what is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: why do you need classes under `src/manual-scripts/java/com`?

Comment: java tests are stored under `src/test/java`, that is enough in most situations

Comment: Generally speaking I would say your build should simply not depend on such scripts. It compromises the reproducibility of your builds. You should try to depend on Maven plugins where possible. If you have something that's not supported by an existing plugin then you could consider writing your own, which would be written in Java (or Scala, Kotlin, etc.)

Comment: Have a look at JUnit tests. Maven automatically picks up these tests and runs them during a build. No need to create an extra plugin or anything else. Just implement the tests and you are done

Comment: This kind of script that I mentioned is not an unit test and neither an integration test. It's just a script that I want to run one-off occasionally if I want to debug a specific piece of code without the needs of running the entire application.
In a interpreted language, I could use a REPL or a simple script, but with Java, I don't know exactly what to use.

Comment: Then make a separate class with a `main` method which does what you need. Then you can run it whenever you need

Comment: Agree with XtremeBaumer. To extend on that comment, I would place the "custom script" main class with my test classes, so that it does not get deployed in production. Run it using the [Maven exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), something as simple as `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=your.fully.qualified.ClassName`.

Comment: oh, this exec plugin is what I was looking for, tks!

Comment: Maven is heavily opinionated. If you don’t work like it would like you to, you will have an uphill battle you most likely will lose.  Spend some time learning maven well.